# Etale lifting of an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question about étale liftings. I take topological rings $A, B, C, D$ such that I have the following commutative diagram :

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    C @>f>> D\\
    @A p AA @AA q A\\
    A @>>g> B
\end{CD}

All the maps are continuous, $p$ and $q$ are étale. I know that $g$ is an isomorphism (with continuous inverse). Is there any chance for $f$ to be invertible too ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: A commutative diagram in your first post ever?! That's a hell of a start! Welcome to MSE.